# Silverlight app. displays "ConfigFileMissing" message when trying to use a web service

Tags: silverlight, web-services

The silverlight class library throws System.InvalidOperationException exception with "ConfigFileMissing" message when trying to access a very simple SOAP web service.

As you can see there's only one line of code that initializes the client.  This is the line where exception happens.

```
public void GetDataFromWebService()
{
   ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient();
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure you have a ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file in the root directoy of your silverlight project.